# Open login logo URL in new tab

Tags: customization, wp-admin, links, wp-login-form

Using `add_filter('login_headerurl', fn() => FRONTEND);` i was able to change the login logo URL.

[image]

But i couldn't find a way to make it open in a new tab.

Or in other words, how can i add target="blank" to the login Logo link?

Kinda like:

```
<h1><a href="https://ex.com/" "title="Some title" target="_blank">Site Name</a></h1>
```

Comment: what is the login logo link? Do you mean the WordPress logo on `wp-login.php`?

Comment: yes that is what i mean